# Xcode tries to install Distribution Profile to device

Tags: xcode, ios4, code-signing

So, I built my app for App Store submission using my distribution profile and submitted it fine.

Now, i come to test my new update on my iPhone, and Xcode keeps telling me

```
"Cant run 'my app' on iPhone 'Joes iPhone'.
The iPhone “Joe’s iPhone” doesn’t have the provisioning profile with
which the application was signed.

Click “Install and Run” to install the provisioning profile 
“Distribution Profile” on “Joe’s iPhone” and continue running “myapp.app”.
```

My configuration is Debug, and the code signing identity is set to iPhone Developer, in both the project and target settings.

How can i get Xcode to start using the developer profile again?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to go to the Project menu and select "Edit Active Target" -- even though my provisioning profiles were right, that target was still set to my App Store release profile, not my development profile.  I don't know the root cause of this, but it did fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is okay. If you click on "Install and Run" XCode will install the provisioning profile to the phone, then will install the application and run it.

Moszi

Comment: I did click on Install and Run and it ran the app, but the message is appearing each time. I was under the impression that The distribution profile should not be used for testing builds, only for app store submission?

Comment: Well this is true. I mean it should be used only for app store. But you should create different configurations like Debug/Release/Distribution and for Debug/Release use the Development provisioning profile and for Distribution then Distribution provisioning profile.

Comment: My Debug configuration uses my Developer profile... which is what i am trying to build and run. Xcode tells me to install the Distribution profile. Its a preference file conflict maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Redownloaded certificates and cleaned all targets

Comment: If this solved the problem, don't forget to accept your own answer by clicking the big tick mark on the left. This marks the answer as the one that solved the problem for the benefit of future readers.